# NumberFormatException thrown when passed date as lowerBound/upperBound in spark-sql-2.4.1v with ojdbc14.jar?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, ojdbc

I have passed lowerBound/upperBound as below

```
Dataset<Row> ss = ora_df_reader
            .option("inferSchema", true)
            .option("schema","schema1")
            .option("numPartitions", 20);
             .option("partitionColumn", "INSERTION_DATE");
            .option("sessionInitStatement", "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD'");
             .option("oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp","false");
             .option("lowerBound", "2002-03-31" ); 
            .option("upperBound", "2019-05-01"); 
            .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd" );
            .option("dbtable", "select * from schema1.modal_vals") 
            .load();
```

When I run the above ,in my local IDE interesting it is running fine without any error.

But when I run the same in the spark-cluster , same giving a number format error ... should I set any parameter in spark cluster in specific?

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2002-03-31"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toLong(StringLike.scala:276)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$9.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$9.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:98)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:34)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:341)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
```

What is the correct the fix here ?

Comment: Is the cluster running an older version of spark, this was fixed in 2.4.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22814 . As seen in these links, the stack trace matches with 2.3 sources, references to `toLong` are gone in 2.4 https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCOptions.scala#L98 vs https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCOptions.scala#L122

Comment: @ollik1 thank you so much for your quick reply ..how to check what spark version it is running ??? ... I added spark jars ...spark-unsafe_2.11-2.4.1.jar
spark-sql_2.11-2.4.1.jar
spark-sketch_2.11-2.4.1.jar
spark-network-shuffle_2.11-2.4.1.jar
spark-network-common_2.11-2.4.1.jar
 spark-launcher_2.11-2.4.1.jar
 spark-kvstore_2.11-2.4.1.jar
 spark-hive_2.11-2.4.1.jar
 spark-core_2.11-2.4.1.jar
 spark-catalyst_2.11-2.4.1.jar

Comment: spark-submit --version

Comment: @ollik1,  it shows version 2.3.2 . is there any way to run on specific version i.e. 2.4.x ? i.e. Run pointing to  2.4.x version without touching anything ?

Comment: AFAIK there is no workarounds. Either install spark 2.4.x or don't use `lowerBound` nor `upperBound`

Comment: @ollik1 thank you , let me check if I can update it

Comment: @ollik1, i installed newer version $ $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit  --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.3
      /_/
But still i am getting same error ...what could be the issue ?

Comment: @ollik1....sorry my mistake ..i was running in old Putty window which is still pointing to 2.3.x.... now i closed it and reopened ...it is running fine.